# BaoFeng UV-82 CTCSS TX static

Tags: tone-squelch

Having an issue with CTCSS tones on the UV82.  The radios seem to be transmitting an audible background sound when CTCSS TX tones are enabled.   This comes through as a slight but noticeable audible buzz when talking UV82 to UV82 and almost completely wiped out the signal when talking to other radios.   Without tones enabled on the Uv82s the transmissions are perfectly clear between all radios.  I tried our same program on a BF-F8hp with the tones enabled and all transmissions from that radio are clear.

For reference the freq is 151.58 and tones is 114.8 and the radios are programmed with Chirp.  Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: These newish HTs are more computer than radio... have you tried to reset the unit? You can just reset the VFO I think, if you have lots of settings you want to save. Though with Chirp as a backup maybe that doesn't matter to you. I'd say do that and [edit] your Q to say if it helped or not.

Comment: A member of my club had the CTCSS deviation setting on his KX3 set too high and it created that resulted in a buzz on his signal. Fortunately the KX3 has an adjustment for that. I don't see one for the UV-82. The specs say deviation is .5+/-.1 kHz in wide mode, and .3+/-.1kHz in narrow mode. If the RX was narrow and TX wide it might do that, but it would also make your audio overly strong at the receiving end as well so I doubt that is the case. I looked at the schematic and can't see any obvious points of adjustment, so it is either fixed or adjustable in some maintenance menu.